# String split() method implementation different from Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: java, string, java-7, java-8

I am not 100% sure if this is a relevant question around here, but I find this thing interesting.

When splitting a string into an array of strings in Java like this:

```
String[] array = "yolo".split("");
```

The implementation in Java 7 and Java 8 is a little bit different.

In Java 8: array.length is 4 and the array looks like this ["y","o","l","o"]

In Java 7: array.length is 5 and the array looks like this ["","y","o","l","o"]

Is this a bug that wasn't fixed until Java 8 (I seem to remember that you would get Java 7 result in older versions of Java aswell)?

Shouldn't code like this be backward compatible, which means that the method should return the same result in Java 7 and Java 8?

Comment: I voted to close this question as duplicate but if you feel that it doesn't fully cover your question inform me about it so I could open it or maybe improve already posted answer.

Comment: Anyway "*Is this a bug that wasn't fixed until Java 8*" I wouldn't call it a bug since it was expected behaviour. What Java8 did was improvement. "*Shouldn't code like this be backward compatible*" generally it should, but since noone really wanted empty `""` as first result of split on `""` (or other zero-width regexes) people in 99.9% of cases ware either removing this first element, or trying to avoid creation of such result by splitting on something like `(?<!^)` - this will check if empty string we are splitting on is not at start of input.

Comment: I totally agree that it is an improvement :) Bug wasn't the right word i guess. This means that one might get some problems running code from the Java7-era on Java 8.

Comment: I assume that Java creators think that combined time spent on solving this problems will be ridiculously smaller than time earned thanks to this change :)